# Hide padlock symbols in Thunar (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, icons, thunar

I manage the computers in our local youth house. I've made an new account and changed the ownership of the desktop folder and icons so they couldn't be edited or removed. Now there's appearing a padlock icon next to every thumbnail. Is there a way to hide those icons without changing the permissions? They are very confusing for some of our members.

Screenshot of the padlock icons:

[image: padlock image]

Comment: You have made the Desktop folder read-only so the icons in the folder get the read-only badge applied. This is by design. Maybe exploring xfce's kiosk mode or using the guest account would be a more viable option.

Comment: I solved the problem by using [xfconfig](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/tree/docs/spec/perchannel-xml.txt). Apparently kiosk mode isn't supported anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a way to hide the icons but solved the problem differently.

1. Give back the write permission to the shortcuts. Desktop folder is still owned by another account and has no write permission.
2. Change desktop settings to your needs
3. Copy $HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml to /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/
4. Edit the file and add the 'unlocked' attribute to the channel tag. For example:

   > ```
   > <channel name="xfce4-desktop" version="1.0" unlocked="@wheel;rvb">
   > ```

   This will only allow members of wheel and the user rvb to change their desktop settings. Other users will use the config file you just copied.